# django form use excluded field

Tags: django, forms, field

with django 1.5.1 I try to use the django form for one of my models. 
I dont want to add the "user" field (Foreignkey) somewhere in the code instead of letting the user deceide whoes new character it is.

My Code:
Model:

```
class Character(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Creation Date')
name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
portrait = models.ForeignKey(Portrait)
faction = models.ForeignKey(Faction)
origin = models.ForeignKey(Origin)
```

The form:

```
class CreateCharacterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Character       
        fields = ['name', 'portrait', 'faction', 'origin']
```

The view:

```
def create_character(request, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

    if request.POST:
        new_char_form = CreateCharacterForm(request.POST)

        if new_char_form.is_valid():
            new_char_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s/characters/' % user_id)

        else:
            return render_to_response('create.html', 
                            {'user': user, 'create_char':new_char_form}, 
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else:
        create_char = CreateCharacterForm
        return render_to_response('create.html', 
                            {'user': user, 'create_char': create_char}, 
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I have tried to use a instance to incluse the userid already. i've tried to save the userid to the form before saving it, or changing the save() from my form.
I keep getting the error that character.user cant be null
I have to tell that im pretty new to django and im sure one way or another it should be possible

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its explained well in document [model form selecting fields to use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use)
You have to do something like this in your view

```
...
if request.POST:
        new_char_form = CreateCharacterForm(request.POST)

        if new_char_form.is_valid():
            #save form with commit=False
            new_char_obj = new_char_form.save(commit=False)
            #set user and save
            new_char_obj.user = user
            new_char_obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s/characters/' % user_id)

        else:
            ...
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the fast response.
I had tried this way, but i see i have to use user  instead of user.id or the user_id from my function.
Thanks alot!